# Why dynamically loaded .NET 6 plugins are no longer IsAssignableFrom the plugin interface when publishing with trim unused assemblies turned on?

Tags: c#, .net-core, plugins, .net-6.0, dotnet-publish

I have created a small .NET 6 console application ([*GPU Offers* on GitHub](https://github.com/soerenkornetzki/GpuOffers)), which is using a [plugin system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support) to dynamically (at runtime) load plugins (DLL files).

When I `dotnet publish` the console app (not the plugins) with the option to *trim unused assemblies*, the plugins don't get recognized as a plugin by the console app anymore...

```cs
private static IEnumerable<IPluginInterface> CreatePlugins(Assembly assembly)
{
    int count = 0;

    foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
    {
        if (typeof(IPluginInterface).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            IPluginInterface result = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IPluginInterface;
            if (result != null)
            {
                count++;
                yield return result;
            }
        }
    }

    if (count == 0)
    {
        string availableTypes = string.Join(", ", Enumerable.Select(assembly.GetTypes(), t => t.FullName));
        throw new ApplicationException(
            $"Can't find any type which implements IPluginInterface in {assembly} from {assembly.Location}.\nAvailable types: {availableTypes}");
    }
}
```

When I disable the *trim unused assemblies* option for the console application, the plugin is recognized again.

In my thought, the `IPluginInterface` cannot be treated as an "unused assembly", as it is actively used in the console application, as you can see above.

**So, why the console application does not recognize the plugins anymore, when the *trim unused assemblies* publish option is enabled?**

Comment: I have the same problem, did you solve it ? It looks like a bug.

Looking in Type.helpers.cs I see :

        [UnconditionalSuppressMessage("ReflectionAnalysis", "IL2085:UnrecognizedReflectionPattern",
            Justification = "The GetInterfaces technically requires all interfaces to be preserved" +
                "But this method only compares the result against the passed in ifaceType." +
                "So if ifaceType exists, then trimming should have kept it implemented on any type.")]
        internal bool ImplementInterface(Type ifaceType)

Comment: I did not have solved it. For now, I do not trim the assemblies, which lead to unnecessary very large files.